# Difference between Input and Output in USB

Tags: usb, documents

I'm relatively new to the the USB field and I have come up with these equations in the USB standard (These equations are in the 5.11.3 section in the [documents](http://sdpha2.ucsd.edu/Lab_Equip_Manuals/usb_20.pdf) and are used to calculate bus transaction times). As I know input and output operate in the same way in the USB, but as you can see here some formulas have different forms for input and output. Can you solve this conflict for me? thanks.

```
High-speed (Input)
    Non-Isochronous Transfer (Handshake Included)
        = (55 * 8 * 2.083) + ( 2.083 * Floor(3.167 + BitStuffTime(Data_bc))) + Host_Delay
    Isochronous Transfer (No Handshake)
        = (38 * 8 * 2.083) + ( 2.083 * Floor(3.167 + BitStuffTime(Data_bc))) + Host_Delay

High-speed (Output)
    Non-Isochronous Transfer (Handshake Included)
        = (55 * 8 * 2.083) + ( 2.083 * Floor(3.167 + BitStuffTime(Data_bc))) + Host_Delay
    Isochronous Transfer (No Handshake)
        = (38 * 8 * 2.083) + ( 2.083 * Floor(3.167 Host_Delay + BitStuffTime(Data_bc))) +

Full-speed (Input)
    Non-Isochronous Transfer (Handshake Included)
        = 9107 + ( 83.54 * Floor(3.167 + BitStuffTime(Data_bc))) + Host_Delay
    Isochronous Transfer (No Handshake)
        = 7268 + ( 83.54 * Floor(3.167 + BitStuffTime(Data_bc))) + Host_Delay

Full-speed (Output)
    Non-Isochronous Transfer (Handshake Included)
        = 9107 + ( 83.54 * Floor(3.167 + BitStuffTime(Data_bc))) + Host_Delay
    Isochronous Transfer (No Handshake)
        = 6265 + ( 83.54 * Floor(3.167 + BitStuffTime(Data_bc))) + Host_Delay

Low-speed (Input)
     = 64060 + (2 * Hub_LS_Setup) + (676.67 * Floor(3.167 + BitStuffTime(Data_bc))) + Host_Delay

Low-speed (Output)
     = 64107 + (2 * Hub_LS_Setup) + (667.0 * Floor(3.167 + BitStuffTime(Data_bc))) + Host_Delay
```

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the formulas carefully, you will see that they are nearly identical for "output" and for "input". The slight difference is only for isochronous transfers due to initial propagation times. Host-to-device transfers don't wait for anything and are faster, while device-to-host transfers involves propagation time for turn-arounds. Why the formulas show LS output slower by 47 ns, I am not sure, could be a typo.

BTW, these formulas are nearly useless, since there is the term "host delay", which will vary depending on system channel response time, so the formulas are largely useless.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Another question is how does these constants like `9107` and `6225` are come from? Can they be represented in similar manner of High-speed, I mean is there a formula like `38 * 8 * 2.083` (which is for High-speed) so that these values be re-calculated?